# How can Teamviewer share images by using direct port behind a firewall

Tags: .net, service, port, remote-desktop

I found this:
[How does teamviewer find my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776971/how-does-teamviewer-find-my-computer-even-if-my-comp-behind-of-the-firewall-and)
but I could not understand and the answers are not what I am looking for.
I'm looking for a solution in .net.

If I have an image-Sender-app and how can Teamviewer connect to image-Receiver-app? Is there any tunnelig system included? Or does Teamviewer only use Port 80?

Does Skype use same methode for voice chat?

*** EXAMPLE ***

I am on PC-A and I have an 50KB image here as Screenshot-Frame and would like to send it to my PC-B. Now, TV (teamviewer) looks on the whole portrange from 1 to 65,000 if any port could connect the SERVER-PC. I think minimum Port 80 will success, right? But on my computer also port 4001 is open, TV will use 4001 for the feature. On PC-B it checks also for open ports and founds port 80 and 6500 and will use 6500 for the feature. My question is now, where are data going to? Is my image first going to SERVER-PC by using port 4001 and the 50KB is stored for short time there and PC-B will download it on port 6500? I cannot believe that that is the truth because it would create too much TV-SERVER-PC traffic. But how can it work?

[image: Image of Port switcher]

Regards

Answer (score 7):

The other answer covers the essentials really.

[This article](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html) (old, but still relevant) describes how Skype gets around firewalls - maybe it helps explain the method better.

As far as I know, TeamViewer employs the exact same method - both TeamViewer client apps connect *actively* to a central server, and then negotiate the connection as described in the article.

> My question is now, where are data going to? Is my image first going to SERVER-PC by using port 4001 and the 50KB is stored for short time there and PC-B will download it on port 6500? I cannot believe that that is the truth because it would create too much TV-SERVER-PC traffic. But how can it work?

PC-A and PC-B communicate directly with each other. SERVER-PC is used only to establish communication between the two, to punch the hole into both computers' firewalls. The crucial trick in the article is this (Emphasis mine):

> Bob's Skype program then punches a hole in its own network firewall: **It sends a UDP packet to 1.1.1.1 port 1414**. This is discarded by Alice's firewall, but Bob's firewall doesn't know that. It now thinks that anything which comes from 1.1.1.1 port 1414 and is addressed to Bob's IP address 2.2.2.2 and port 2828 is legitimate - it must be the response to the query which has just been sent.

Comment: thanks for your comment. please, I updated my question with an example to show where I have the big questionmark. Can you try to answer?

Comment: @goldengel I added some more detail, maybe it helps.

Comment: @community. I made 100 bounties and cannot send it now to Pekka.

Comment: @goldengel when the bounty expires, the community user awards half of the amount that you sponsored. It's fine - I just hope the information helps

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks that sounds good. When installing now PC-A application. I need to send a UDP packet on port 1414 to open firewall there as I understood. But how to switch the port while receiving from Alice's 2828 image to my local 1414? Where to switch this port? I made an image in question. Please see the "green boxed portswitcher" which I don't know what is is really.

Comment: @goldengel I assume the port number is information that is sent to the central server, so PC-A knows which port to target on PC-B and vice versa... I'm not really familiar with communication on protocol level, so I can't give any more detail here, sorry

Comment: But that is the key question. Because if port is switched on server, what is about data?

Answer (score 1):

The first answer in the other Teamviewer question is correct - it uses a central server to work through firewalls - probably falling back to making HTTP POSTs with the more restrictive firewalls. This way the two Teamviewers are not communicating with each other, only with the central server.

Comment: I am not asking for code voltagex you missunderstood. I want to know the tools to get stuff working using DotNet. I updated my question.

Comment: Create a webservice that receives images from A. Have a method for B to receive images. Your client A sends {image,ID, for-b}. Your client B requests {image,for-b} and downloads all available images.

Comment: Ok, that sound like default way how to share image. The keyquestion is why is your description not working on firewalls but TV can do this? What port is used? (in the example on my question)